# How to enable BCMath CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos

How would I go about installing/enabling PHP bcmath module on CentOS 6?

I've tried '**yum install php-bcmath**' and got this error:

```
   Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Removing: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (@updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
       Updated By: php-common-5.5.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.6-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php-common-5.5.5-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.5-2.el6.remi
  Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
       Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
```

It looks like there are some dependencies I am missing yet I am not too clued up on how to go about installing these. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch. Looks like you've got dueling repos there. The problem is that you've got 5.3 and 5.5 packages (looks like remi 5.5 repo). 5.3 is installed (`Removing: php-common-5.3.3-23`) but that repo probably doesn't have `php-bcmath` so yum went to remi and found it there, but that package says it needs 5.5 installed so yum is stuck trying to take out 5.3 and install 5.5 instead, but 5.5 has some other dependencies not satisfied.

So, a couple of options

1. Just upgrade PHP to 5.5. You might need the [base remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) to do that (I bet that libgd library is in there)
2. Turn off the remi 5.5 repo (edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and set `enabled=0` on the 5.5 repo). If you're not going to 5.5 you don't need it enabled anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I simply set that line to 0 and try again?

Comment: That one line change will prevent yum from checking that repo at all. Hopefully another repo has it instead, one that will work with your install of PHP